# Perl question mark followed by colon pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl

I have following perl pattern matching condition

```
(?:\s+\w+){2}
```

When it's applied on a Linux directory listing

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root       36547 2011-03-18 18:41 abc.txt
```

It matches `root root`

What is `?:` doing in this?

Comment: It should match `1 root`. How do you get that output?

Comment: `(?: )` is used to apply tell the engine what `{2}` applies to. `\s+\w+{2}` makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets capture the string found in a regex. `?:` will disable the capturing for the current bracket.

"1 root" is matched because the pattern matches two occurrences of one or more whitespace characters (`\s`) followed by one it more word characters (`\w`). See "[Character Classes and other Special Escapes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)".

In the example given, the 1st word character that has a whitespace in front is "1", followed by some whitespace and again, one or more word characters.

For those who don't see it - try it out (you can remove the `?:` to see the matching group `$1`, it will contain root):

```
my $str = '-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     36574 2011-03-18 18:41 abc.txt';
if ( $str =~ m/(\s+\w+){2}/ ) {
    print "matches\n";
    print "\$1 contains " . (defined $1 ? $1 : "nothing it's undef") . "\n";
}else{
    print "does not match\n";
}
```